# How to find out what router is responsible for packet loss?

Tags: networking, windows-10, internet-connection

I am using Windows an tried `pathping`, but `pathping 8.8.8.8` will only show the first hop from my pc to my fritzbox. I read that an ISP might deactivate that function on their hardware.
A normal traceroute using `tracert` will always show the correct path when the internet is not really, really bad. But `ping 8.8.8.8` will show a lot of timeouts.
So how can I find out, where the packet loss occurs?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you can use [WinMTR](http://winmtr.net/) for that purpose.
It is really a shame, that `pathping` seems to get stuck when a router does not respond to ICMP-requests and you can not even tell it to ignore such routers.